# root filesystem auto mounts in recovery mode (Ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: 20.10, recovery-mode

I need to get to recovery mode so I can run `zerofree` on my root partition before shrinking the hard disk (it's a virtual machine hard disk).

When I boot to recovery mode (via grub), it mounts `/` and I can't unmount it (`target is busy`). All of the stuff I find says that `/` should not be mounted when I go into recovery mode and all my searches result in pages that instruct you on how to mount it.

How do I figure out what's going on and get into recovery mode without `/` being mounted?

Comment: You cannot unmount an active device. If you would like to access `/` while it is unmounted, you will need to boot using the Ubuntu Live `.iso`. From there you can do what you need to do with the storage devices.

Comment: @Matigo - this how I have always done it - boot into recovery mode with grub, which runs a temporary fs and doesn't mount `/`.